# Alternatives to pop-up in JSF

Tags: html, modal-dialog, popup

Modal pop-ups feel like ugly work-arounds in web applications. They seem to be hard to manage, can have problems with pop-up blockers, and the modality can create user confusion.

What are alternatives to pop-ups for the 2 following scenarios:

1. A user confirmation (eg. delete confirm)
2. A forced user workflow (eg. user must select an image to continue)

Or if a pop-up is the best UI, is there a good library to supply it for each scenario?

Comment: have a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: Popup blockers won't block overlay divs like `<p:dialog>` http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogHome.jsf

Comment: a dialog is the better alternative.
if you're using dojo, the dijit system has a nice dialog creating system, in jQuery, you'll need to use the jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

As @unwichtich suggested in the comments, [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) provides a good modal dialog with different types of actions required by the user.

Alternatively, you could redirect the user to a page where she has to confirm whatever needs confirming or asking and only let them pass forward.

Answer (score 0):

Since we generally use RichFaces, I can provide you an alternative to pop-ups in rich faces.
Use

```
   <rich:panel>
```

with appropiate style property to show a pop-up panel..

I am sure a corresponding thing in prime faces should also be present.